# Simplify two filters in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there a way to simplify this scala code into a for comprehension?

```
val selectedNames = names filter {setOfNames}
val selectedPersons = persons filter {p => seletectedNames contains p.name}
```

Here I'm assuming that persons have a name attribute.

**Edit**

Of course the value names is obtained as

```
val names = persons map _.name
```

Comment: _for comprehension_ is used as syntactic sugar for the application of a sequence of `filter`, `flatmap` and `map` functions. Here you miss the `map` and `flatMap` part ;)

Comment: As far as I can understand from your code, I think that a simpler way to accomplish the task is to filter directly `persons` list through their name, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is much of a simplification. It's just doing the same thing via a `for` comprehension as requested.

```
val selectedPersons = for {
  p <- persons
  if setOfNames(p.name)
} yield p
```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
val selectedPersons = persons filter { person => setOfNames contains person.name }
```